How to hide server details(Kestrel) in response headers for Function Hosted applications in .NET8?
I'm working on an Azure Function Hosted application and I need to hide the server details from the response headers. I tried the following code, but it didn't work:
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
   webBuilder.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false);
})

I also tried this code also, but it's not applicable because it's for a WebApplication:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false);

Additionally, we do not use web.config in our setup. How can I hide the server details from the response headers in a Function Hosted application?

I have added this
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request;Exception;Trace;Dependency"
      },
      "enableDependencyTracking": true
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "api",
      "customHeaders": {
        "Server": ""
      }
    }
  }
}

but it didn't work, am I missing something?
Postman Response

I have also tried to hide the Kestrel server details in .NET 8.0 isolated Azure function using webBuilder.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false);, but it didnt work as expected.
The only way I found to hide the server details is to set the Server header as empty or null in the custom header section in host.json.
Thanks clientbala for the workaround.
host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "customHeaders": {
        "Server": ""
      }
    }
  }
}


Able to set the Server header empty as below:



I have added this
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request;Exception;Trace;Dependency"
},
"enableDependencyTracking": true
}
},
"extensions": {
"http": {
"routePrefix": "api",
"customHeaders": {
"Server": ""
}
}
}
}But still server is visible

Please share the screenshot of it and also host.json.

was unable to add in comment so I shared in answer section

Can you remove routePrefix in host.json and check

Yes I checked, I added because of warning, as it was required field

Did you remove webBuilder.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false);?

Yes, I have removed other changes

I tried with your host.json and I could still see the server details, refer Image. To make server details empty, you have to use the code  webBuilder.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false); as well along with the host.json configuration.

@ASHWANIMAURYA, is the issue resolved?

Yes, it worked after adding this webBuilder.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false); along with host.json configurations.
thanks

working on the local host but when I deployed with both the changes I am getting Server Unavailable issue with the endpoints. @Pravallika KV

Just for your information, my Function app is on .NET8 (isolated model)
